# How to calculate the ways to paint a tree?

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-coloring

How to calculate the ways to paint a tree's nodes with m colors so that the ends of each edge have different colors?

Any polynomial solution is welcome.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for number of ways.

Comment: Does it have to use all m colors?

Comment: You don't need any algorithm, you just need to apply a `O(1)` formula (assuming you don't have to count nodes first): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial#Examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have m choices for the root. If you paint going down from the root, you have m-1 choices for each additional node. If the number of nodes is n, then the number of ways to paint the tree is m * (m-1)^(n-1).

Comment: what about n=1 and m=1 in your solution?

Comment: @dd2 put `n=1` and `m=1` in the given formula and you will get the correct answer as I mentioned in the comment to your answer.

Comment: @dd2 0^0=1. It's a convention, and not one that's commonly taught. https://www.quora.com/What-is-0-0-the-zeroth-power-of-zero-1